# Graphs on diagrams and on equipotence

Tags: graphics, venn-diagrams

Could someone help me to make the following graphs. Thanks.[image]

What I tried for the diagrams was the following,

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (-3.3,-0.4)node[right] {$1$};
 \draw (-3.3,-0.8)node[right] {$2$};
 \draw (-3.3,-1.2)node[right] {$3$};
 \draw (-3.3,-1.6)node[right] {$4$};
 \draw (-3.2222,-2)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (-3.2222,-2.4)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (-3.6,-3) node[right] {$n-1$};
 \draw (-3.3,-3.4) node[right] {$n$};
 \draw (-0.3,-0.4)node[right] {$a_1$};
 \draw (-0.3,-0.8)node[right] {$a_2$};
 \draw (-0.3,-1.2)node[right] {$a_3$};
 \draw (-0.3,-1.6)node[right] {$a_4$};
 \draw (-0.2222,-2)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (-0.2222,-2.4)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (-0.3,-3) node[right] {$a_{n-1}$};
 \draw (-0.3,-3.4) node[right] {$a_n$};

 \draw (2.6,-0.4)node[right] {$b_1$};
 \draw (2.6,-0.8)node[right] {$b_2$};
 \draw (2.6,-1.2)node[right] {$b_3$};
 \draw (2.6,-1.6)node[right] {$b_4$};
 \draw (2.7,-2)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (2.7,-2.4)node[right] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (2.6,-3) node[right] {$b_{n-2}$};
 \draw (2.6,-3.4) node[right] {$b_{n-1}$};
 \draw (-3,-2) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
 \draw (-3.1,0.3) node {$J_n$};
 \draw (0,-2) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
 \draw (-0.1,0.3) node {$A$};
 \draw (3,-2) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
 \draw (2.8,0.3) node {$B$};
 \draw [->](-2,0) -- (-1,0);
 \draw (-1.5,0.3) node {$\phi$};
 \draw[->](1,0) -- (2,0);
 \draw (1.5,0.3) node {$f$};
 \draw[->] (-3,-0.4) -- (-0.2,-2.9);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
```

Which threw me the following graph (I made it with three diagrams)
[image]

The issue is that they are too large and I do not know how to make those points of the diagrams. I don't how to draw one similar to the third graph.

Comment: Well what have you tried?

Comment: You can look at my edit. @M.A.Bromuela

Comment: Nicely done, it's great that you've shown us what you've done so far :) hopefully someone will be able to help

Comment: Are dots necessary? The one in the example graphs?

Comment: Well, if they are necessary. I would like to know how they are put, to take it into account in future graphics. @M.A.Bromuela

Comment: possible helpful posts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/drawing-a-bijective-map-with-tikz, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79009/drawing-the-mapping-of-elements-for-sets-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56139/tikz-diagram-showing-range-domain-and-co-domain-of-a-function

Comment: Thanks, sir. I appreciate the help. are too helpful that pages :). @cmhughes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay tried to replicate the way according to the example. For the first problem, you may define dots with `filldraw` command and make circle dots of  size `1pt`. And I assume you know how to draw arrows already. I changed the appearance of the arrow tip using `latex'`. For the second problem, I used a separate standalone document to show how the graphic appears with the code. You can resize them with the `resize` command but it also makes the letters appear smaller, so be warned.

For the first problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick] (-3,-1.9) ellipse (1.1cm and 1.875cm);
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-0.4) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$1$};
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-0.8) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$2$};
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-1.2) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$3$};
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-1.6) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$4$};
 \draw (-2.79,-2) node[anchor=east] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (-2.79,-2.4) node[anchor=east] {$\vdots$};
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-3) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$n-1$};
 \filldraw[black] (-2.765,-3.4) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$n$};
 
 \draw[thick] (0.1,-1.9) ellipse (1.1cm and 1.875cm);
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-0.4) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_1$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-0.4) circle (1pt);
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-0.8) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_2$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-0.8) circle (1pt);
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-1.2) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_3$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-1.2) circle (1pt);
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-1.6) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_4$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-1.6) circle (1pt);
 \draw[black] (-0.1,-2) node[anchor=west] {$\vdots$};
 \draw[black] (-0.1,-2.4) node[anchor=west] {$\vdots$};
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-3) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_{n-1}$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-3) circle (1pt);
 \filldraw[black] (-0.36,-3.4) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$a_n$};
 \filldraw[black] (0.6,-3.4) circle (1pt);
 
 \draw[thick] (3.2,-1.9) ellipse (1.1cm and 1.875cm);
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-0.4) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_1$};
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-0.8) circle(1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_2$};
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-1.2) circle(1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_3$};
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-1.6) circle(1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_4$};
 \draw (3,-2) node[anchor=west] {$\vdots$};
 \draw (3,-2.4) node[anchor=west] {$\vdots$};
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-3) circle(1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_{n-2}$};
 \filldraw[black] (2.8,-3.4) circle(1pt) node[anchor=west] {$b_{n-1}$};

 \draw (-3,0.3) node {$J_n$};
 \draw (-0.1,0.3) node {$A$};
 \draw (3.2,0.3) node {$B$};
 \draw [->](-2,0) -- (-1,0);
 \draw (-1.5,0.3) node {$\phi$};
 \draw[->](1,0) -- (2,0);
 \draw (1.5,0.3) node {$f$};
 
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-0.4) -- (-0.35,-0.4);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-0.8) -- (-0.35,-0.8);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-1.2) -- (-0.35,-1.2);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-1.6) -- (-0.35,-1.6);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-3) -- (-0.355,-3);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (-2.7,-3.4) -- (-0.35,-3.4);
 
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-0.4) -- (2.7,-1.2);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-0.8) -- (2.7,-3);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-1.2) -- (2.7,-0.4);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-1.6) -- (2.7,-0.8);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-3) -- (2.7,-1.6);
 \draw[thick, -latex'] (0.7,-3.4) -- (2.7,-3.4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 
 \end{document}
```

[image: Relations]

For the second problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,16} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0.5pt) -- (0pt,0pt) node[anchor=south] {$\x$};
\draw[black,thick, latex-latex] (0,0) -- (17,0);
\foreach[evaluate={\j=int{\x+5}}] \x in {-7,...,8}{\draw[shift={(\j,-3)},color=black] (0pt,0.5pt) -- (0pt,0pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};};
\draw[black,thick, latex-latex] (-3,-3) -- (15,-3);
%\draw[shift={(\x,-3)},color=black] (0pt,0.5pt) -- (0pt,0pt) node[anchor=south] {$\x$};

\draw[thick, -latex'] (4,0) -- (4,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (2,0) -- (5,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (16,0) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (14,0) -- (-1,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (12,0) -- (0,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (10,0) -- (1,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (8,0) -- (2,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (6,0) -- (3,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (15,0) -- (13,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (13,0) -- (12,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (11,0) -- (11,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (9,0) -- (10,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (7,0) -- (9,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (5,0) -- (8,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (3,0) -- (7,-3);
\draw[thick, -latex'] (1,0) -- (6,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Equipotence]

Comment: I really didn't gave the time for the alignments. You may also try shortening the code for the second problem for drawing the arrows, perhaps with `foreach` with `evaluate` option. But I hope that sums this up.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.